# Aws cloudwatch contributor insights filtering wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Filtering logs in cloudwatch contributor insights StartsWith filter should support wildcards(as UI suggests), Star wildcard like *usergroup did not work. And when I have special characters like slash and colon it filters out everything.

Example of filter syntax that i use when i want to filter for value containg semicolons and slashes:

```
{
    "AggregateOn": "Count",
    "Contribution": {
        "Filters": [
            {
                "Match": "$.userIdentity",
                "StartsWith": [
                    "abc:8923879:aa/usergroup"
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

Example of filter syntax that i use when i want to filter with wildcards:

```
{
    "AggregateOn": "Count",
    "Contribution": {
        "Filters": [
            {
                "Match": "$.userIdentity",
                "StartsWith": [
                    "*usergroup"
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to use StartsWith filter *usergroup to be able to filter only logs that have user from this group. Also if the value contains characters like slash, colon i expect that it will work, or maybe i need some escaping.

How to use wildcards? How should i escape non alphanumeric values?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What's the question here? Is it regarding wildcard support or your filter syntax? Please make the question more focused and concise.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The question is how to use wildcards and when i want to use non alphanumeric values in the filter, how to escape them. My syntax is just an example for the context what values i have in logs. Docs for that only use plain values, no wildcards https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContributorInsights-RuleSyntax.html